# check for data gap MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a sample matrix in foll. format:. 1st column shows year & 2nd value. Each year value corresponds to each months so there are 12 number of 1926 in 
each row. There are 1000s of text files like this in a directory and each file contains year value starting from 1926 and ends to 2013. For sample purpose,
I restricted here upto 1927 year value. In matrix A, I need to check each year value for Nan (2nd column), if in a given year more than 6 Nans in a year,
I need to reject that station, or if less than this accept that. Can anybody suggest some simple algorithm how to check whether each row contains complete 12 months or not or if more than 6 missing values? For example, in Matrix A year 1926 has 7 missing values, then check for year 1927 and so on upto year 2013.

```
A = [1926   NaN
     1926   Nan
     1926   Nan
     1926   90.424
     1926   127.762
     1926   172.212
     1926   Nan
     1926   Nan 
     1926   Nan
     1926   Nan
     1926   82.296
     1926   89.916
     1927   25.146
     1927   233.68
     1927   127.254
     1927   22.606
     1927   57.15
     1927   185.674
     1927   112.776
     1927   178.562
     1927   110.998
     1927   80.264
     1927   142.24
     1927   237.998
      :        :
     2013     : ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `histc`, `unique` and `accumarray` to solve your case -

```
%// Id each year and find unique year entries
[unqA,~,year_id] = unique(A(:,1)); 

%// Find the two outputs of whether there are 12 months data and 
%// more than 6 NaNs per year as per the problem requirements
out1 = histc(A(:,1),unqA)==12
out2 = accumarray(year_id,isnan(A(:,2)))>6
```

How to interpret the outputs -

`out1` and `out2` are logical vectors (1s and 0s) of lengths equal to unique number of year entries in the first column. A `1` in `out1` means there are `12` months entries for that specific year. A `1` in `out2` means there are more than `6` months entries with `NaNs` for that year and thus, you need to *reject that solution*.

Thus, if you want to consider or select only those row entries corresponding to the years that have all `12 months` of data and not more than `6 NaNs` per year, you can do this -

```
Aout = A(ismember(year_id,find(out1)) & ismember(year_id,find(~out2)),:)
```

If you would like to fill up those `NaN` entries for the years which have less than `6 NaNs` by [`knnimpute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/knnimpute.html) values, you can do this -

```
A_filled = knnimpute(A) %// knnimputed values for the entire array, A
out3 = accumarray(year_id,isnan(A(:,2)))<6
fillpos = ismember(year_id,find(out3))
A(fillpos,:) = A_filled(fillpos,:)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another question is how I can take 12 months as a chunk from 1926 to 2013 in a loop to infill missing value. I know for filling missing data I can use Knn impute in Bio-informatics tool box.

Comment: @user962808 Edit the question with some sample values on how you would like to *infill* values?

Comment: I was thinking of imputing the value using knnimpute eucledian norm for all months in a given year if there are less than 6 months of missing data. But not sure how I can include in a script.

Comment: @user962808 Check out the edits at the end of the post?

Comment: Thanks! But I need to employ Knn impute based on 12 months value in a given year, not on the entire record.I mean first search for missing data in 1926, if it is less than 6, impute it. Then move to 1927, check whether there's less than 6 missing value, impute it if no then move to 1928 and so on. Is there a way out for that?

Comment: @user962808 Have you actually tested this on your data?